# pygame.error: SavePNG: could not open for writing?

Tags: python, image, crash, save, pygame

I have written a program in Python which draws parts of the Mandelbrot set using pygame. However, when I leave it running to generate for a long time and then save the file I get this error:

> pygame.error: SavePNG: could not open for writing

I'm not sure why this would happen and saving works fine usually. Perhaps when the computer goes to sleep something stops working? But more importantly does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Where are you opening the file for writing? What's the code you're using? Are you running your script/program in `sudo` or `administrator` mode?

Comment: What's the full traceback? How big is the image you try to save when the program runs for a long time? Does it work if you save an image only after 2 minutes?

Comment: The image is 1024x1024, saving works after 2 minutes or even a full image which can take hours but doesnt seem to work if I leave the computer while its running. Im running the script directy from inside the python 3.4.1 ide and the line to save the image is: pygame.image.save(surface,'image.png')

Answer (score 0):

Are you on windows or on mac? If you're on windows look if you wrote the location like this
"\folder\thing.png", that's an error because you put the starting "\". Remove that and try again.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).